# Libgdx android resize and create lifecycle

Tags: android, libgdx

I am creating a live wallpaper with libgdx. On the create method I init all the things that I want use later.

But when the screen rotates the create method run again and all the things. Is it any way to cache that loaded things to load only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the objects exist in the create method and only if they don't already exist create them. E.g

```
if(gameObject == null){
    gameObject = new GameObject(params);
}
```

Comment: It is always null. I dispose all my things in dispose ()

Comment: How about using something like an asset manager that loads and holds your resources?

Comment: I think that will be the same. Not?

Comment: If you have the asset manager in a parent class the asset manager won't be disposed and keep the assets loaded. You can then dispose the asset manager and all assets when exiting the application. If the asset manager method is a bit much you could even add a Boolean flag that disabled the disposing of resources when the onSurfaceChanged method is called.

Comment: Unfortunatly its a live wallpaper